# node.js - socket.io 404 not found

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using express 3.x. Loading socket.io client-side gives me a 404 error.

#### app.js

```
var express =       require('express'),
app =           express(),
http =          require('http'),
path =          require('path'),
favicon =       require('static-favicon'),
logger =        require('morgan'),
cookieParser =  require('cookie-parser'),
bodyParser =    require('body-parser'),
server =        http.createServer(app),
io =            require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(app.get('port'));

//connecting to server
io.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

//read to client
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('DAMN RIGHT');
    socket.emit('news', {message: 'DAMN RIGHT'});
});
```

#### .jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src="./socket.io/socket.io.js")
  body
    div#template
    div#startscreen

    block content
```

The browser shows socket.io 404 not found.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `.` and check

```
script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

You can `also` use your socket.io server to serve the JS

```
script(src='http://localhost:port/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

You can `also` use a CDN

```
script(src='https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js')
```

Comment: Edit your question a teeny bit and I'll remove the downvote (it won't let me until you edit it).  I misread what your first part meant.  I thought you were telling them to remove the local script reference and use a CDN instead (which is a generally bad idea).

Comment: well! no I didn't mean that. Anyways I have edited the answer.

Comment: Note to the OP: Using a CDN removes advantages of using the self-served version so I would not recommend that option.  When you let the socket.io code server the client JS, you are guaranteed that both client and server socket.io libraries are always of the same version without doing any extra work.  If you use a CDN, you must manually make sure the two are always in sync.